# Couldn't people see Wayne was alive and link his disappearance to Batman's "death"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

So there should have been people who, at the beginning of *The Dark Knight Rises*, could make the connection between Wayne's hermit-like lifestyle and the disappearance of Batman.

At the end of the movie, we see Wayne with Selina Kyle, and his "death" timed spectacularly well with the "death" of Batman.

Wouldn't people make the connections, and ultimately realize this? And since Gotham is a huge city, and Batman is probably known around the world, wouldn't people see a well and alive Bruce Wayne and be like, oh, Batman is still alive?

Comment: Bruce Wayne's public persona was a polar opposite to Batman. Sure, as a reader/viewer we are inclined to connect the dots, but for people in this fictional world to speculate that the two are the same, just based on coincidence, may not be so practical.

Comment: There's more timing coincidences than that even. 1) Bruce Wayne returns to Gotham after many years; and Batman first shows up right then. 2) Batman goes into hiding at the same time Bruce Wayne becomes a shut-in. 3) Batman reappears after many years; at the same time Bruce Wayne makes his first public appearance in a long time. 4) Bruce Wayne and Batman die at the same time.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think so. a lot of people got killed/executed/executed by exile and died in so many fights **and rich people were specifically targeted**, so people would just assume he was one of the many victims, and if there were any one already think Wayne is batman, it will remain just a theory with no real evidence.

Also if someone saw Bruce (if he's really alive) and it became a known fact that he's still alive, that actually will dispute that theory not prove it. It will be like "My theory was wrong and their disappearings was just a coincidence since Wayne turned out to be alive and we all know that batman died!"

I guess someone might get suspicious if both came back from an alleged death though.

Answer (score 1):

Bruce's last public appearance was after the stock exchange robbery and before Bane's revolution which targeted the upper class. Bruce's funeral was private so the deaths aren't connected, especially when you consider the time it would take for Gotham City to rebuild it's infrastructure.

Bruce's public image is exclusive to Gotham City so he wouldn't be recognized in Florence. In Batman Begins he traveled the world for 7 years and in The Dark Knight no paparazzi or photographers follow him in Hong Kong.

There are probably conspiracy theories linking Bruce and other billionaires with the identity of Batman since he returned to Gotham in the first film.